# How does radius vary with time for cloud chamber particles?

Tags: particle-physics, momentum

I know that particle information can be extracted from studying cloud chamber gas, but I was wondering how the radius of a particle decreases with time as the surrounding gas molecules do work on it?

$r = p/Bq$

So for radius to decrease as particles spiral inwards, $p$ must decrease. Is there an expression for how radius varies with time in this situation?

Level: High school physics, but more advanced maths/theory welcome.

Comment: The kinetic energy is proportional to the total distance travelled by the particle before it is stopped by the cloud chamber gas collisions. I think that should be enough to find the answer to your question using some algebra. Although that's more 2nd year college level I would say.

Comment: @Virgo That statements assumes a constant acceleration, which is approximately true only over part of the possible tracks. Both relativity and Bragg peaking interfere with it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no expression that I know of.The loss of energy is due to ionization loss , the one that generates the track footprint in the chamber, and it will depend on the specific composition of the gas in a gas chamber or the liquid in a bubble chamber.  It may be possible to derive an analytic formula, except it has not been necessary.

The reason we study the tracks is to determine the momentum at the initial interaction vertex, and one approximates a circle at the beginning of the track, in order to get it. In particle physics the energies are so high that this beginning of the track fit gives small enough errors not to have to complicate the analysis.

The energy loss for various situations can be seen [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf) . And [here is](http://hep.ucsb.edu/people/hnn/cloud/articles/cloudchamber.pdf) a report on tracks that have been studied in a cloud chamber.

Comment: *"There is no expression that I know of."* Well, for relatively heavy particle there will be a period when they are near minimum ionization, and we can presumably find a nice analytic approximation for the shape of the curve. Perhaps I'll work that out and consider making it a problem for one of my classes.